# Em R: como agrupar os resultados de um loop em uma função rbind?

Tags: r, loop, while

Considerando que possuo um dataframe chamado `page` cujo número de linhas varia regularmente, escrevi esse código para que ele se ajuste ao número de linhas que meu `page$id` possui e escrevi esse `while` para que ele gere um `"g_com[numero]"` para cada uma dessas linhas.

```
meu page$id contém:
[1] "1793398447353793"
[2] "1792916894068615"
[3] "1792013524158952"
[4] "1791520780874893"
continua...
```

Esse é o script que estou rodando:

```
binds    <- as.data.frame(page$id)
contador <- 1

while (contador <= length(page$id)) { 
  binds[contador] <- paste0 ("g_com", contador)
  contador        <- contador + 1
}

b <- binds [1,]
```

Ele está devolvendo uma tabela com 17 colunas e uma linha em cada:

```
> print(binds)
page$id     V2     V3     V4     V5
1       g_com1, g_com2, g_com3, g_com4, g_com5,
```

No entanto, preciso agrupar automaticamente todos esses `"g_com"` em uma sentença, para que ele fique sem a vírgula após o último elemento e possa ser apresentado em uma única linha, e não em colunas, preciso rodar um rbind neles, então preciso que ele retorne algo do tipo

```
g_com1, g_com2, g_com3, ..., g_com17
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Comment: Como eu comentei na tua pergunta anterior, fica muito complicado te ajudar com uma pergunta assim tão genérica. Tenta te colocar no lugar de quem está lendo a pergunta, que não conhece `page`, `page$id` e tudo o mais. É complicado testar nossas propostas de solução sem um conjunto de dados para aplicá-la. [Veja esta lista de perguntas respondidas sobre o R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5br%5d%20hasaccepted%3ayes) e perceba que as pessoas que fizeram elas foram objetivas, dando informações necessárias para quem estivesse disposto a ajudar.

Comment: @Marcus Nunes, tentei melhorar a pergunta e a descrição dos dados. Ficou melhor? Obrigada pelas dicas, mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1):

Eu gerei alguns dados aleatórios, pois não tenho acesso aos originais. Veja se o comando `paste(unlist(b[2:length(b)]), collapse=", ")`, ao final do código, te ajuda.

```
page <- data.frame(id=rpois(17, lambda=100000))

binds    <- as.data.frame(page$id)
contador <- 1

while (contador <= length(page$id)) { 
  binds[contador] <- paste0("g_com", contador)
  contador        <- contador + 1
}

b <- binds [1,]

print(b)
  page$id     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9     V10
1  g_com1 g_com2 g_com3 g_com4 g_com5 g_com6 g_com7 g_com8 g_com9 g_com10
      V11     V12     V13     V14     V15     V16     V17
1 g_com11 g_com12 g_com13 g_com14 g_com15 g_com16 g_com17

paste(unlist(b[2:length(b)]), collapse=", ")
[1] "g_com2, g_com3, g_com4, g_com5, g_com6, g_com7, g_com8, g_com9, g_com10, 
g_com11, g_com12, g_com13, g_com14, g_com15, g_com16, g_com17"
```

Não consigo ver como o código fornecido gerou os dados originais com vírgulas, posto que o código não é reproduzível.